# Find location by zip code

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-geocoding-api

I am looking for a google API or any other API that returns me location ( in the form of latitude/longitude or place name )

Using Geocoder I can find lat,long as long as I know the name of place.

It can we a web service or some query to some online database. I don't want to populate the US Zip codes to a local database.

Comment: see this question... http://stackoverflow.com/a/8180571/720176

Comment: send the pincode to google map geocoder web service it will give address and also give lat and long value

Comment: Can you give me the link of the google api which takes in pincode as the request and gives me lat, lng as the response.

Comment: You can use https://www.thezipcodes.com/ as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google's webservice and the Javascript geocoder both geocode zipcodes on their own without  an explicit placename. There is a rate limit and a daily limit with both. Google's Terms of Service don't permit permanent storage of geocoded data — which you don't intend to do — but they do mandate displaying the geocoded point(s) on a Google map (which you may not be intending to do).

Five-digit zipcodes default to the USPS codes, I believe. For other countries' five-digit codes you need to specify the country.

#### Edit:

Documentation for Javascript API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding
Example for Javascript API: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple (try entering **90210**)
Documentation for webservice: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/
Example request: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=90210&sensor=false

You may find that certain countries' postal codes don't work. But to make the blanket statement *they are not providing location search based on zipcode* is not correct. If you are having difficulty with a particular country's postal codes — like India's PIN code perhaps — it's best to be specific.

#### Edit #2:

If you are interested in Indian pincodes then a top-ranking Google result was this thread: https://groups.google.com/group/datameet/browse_thread/thread/db5b8a3f4033ae36

Comment: I have already checked Google API, they are not providing location search based on zipcode.. in case I have missed that please provide me the url.

Comment: Indian pincodes link is incorrect. Can you please put in a detailed answer in addition to a valid link please.

Comment: @Siddharth There's nothing more to add to the documentation, and the last link *does* work. Using Google's example at https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple, `506102, India` is located in Mumbai. So at least some pincodes do work with Google's geocoer.

Answer (score 2):

[GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) provides several geolocation related [web services](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html) including lat/long information for zip codes.

Comment: Thanks, this is somewhat what I was looking for, one more question is do Google has an API similar to GeoNames. I mean a webservice that does similar thing like GeoNames.

Answer (score 0):

There are some public webservices on the internet - here's one that returns place names (and other information) for zip codes:

- [USZip](http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx) (Select GetInfoByZIP)

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the UK then the only way to effectively do this using Google Maps API is to write it in javascript due to the limitation Google place on the number of API calls per day from a single IP address.

If yous solution is going to be under moderate usage load then you may want to look at a solution that utilises the UK Royal Mail PAF file.   One such service that I've integrated with for my work is Postcode Anywhere (www.postcodeanywhere.com).  They have a great API available in various formats... it was the easiest integration I've done lately.